# Get element from iFrame error: Domains, protocols and ports must match

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, dns

Hi i have an issue with getting an element from iFrame. I get this error in the console when i'm trying to get an element from a website.

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL
>   localhost/website from frame with URL www.tv.nu/.
>   Domains, protocols and ports must match.

How remove this so i can get the elements html into my string?

This is my code, where i get the element from the iFrame every second.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function GetFrameData() {
        var $MyFrame = $("#iframeid");
        var frameBody = $MyFrame.contents().find('body');
        var inf = frameBody.find('.theid').html();
}
setInterval(GetFrameData, 1000);
</script>
```

Best regards

Daniel

Comment: You can't access cross domain Iframes..  [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: hmm... is there another way to get element from a website.. like rss?

Comment: Do you have control over the different domain? There is a way if you can add Javascript on both sides.

Comment: nope i want to do i similar to rss.

Comment: Then the last thing that remains is to load the iframe as a string with HTML and put it in your document as a div. You can do that with either PHP (cURL) or JS (AJAX, JSOPN). If you choose JS, there is a good way to start: http://ajaxian.com/archives/using-yql-as-a-proxy-for-cross-domain-ajax